# Help with irrigation pump selection

Tags: water, pump, irrigation

I want to set up a temporary irrigation system in my yard for this summer and maybe the next.

I have a dug well (15-16m deep), and already an 800W submersible pump in it, which will fill up a tank next to the house, controlled by a float switch.

The question is about the irrigation circuit: i'm planning with 2 irrigation zones, one for an annual flower bed - with perforated tube and a smaller vegetable garden with rotating sprinklers. (I don't want to use drip irrigation in the vegetable garden, because the layout is not fixed yet.) I purchased a low-cost 4 zone irrigation controller, which can control 4 valves, and has an MV (master valve) output, which I could use to start the irrigation pump through a contactor.

I need help with the selection of the irrigation pump. As I see, I have 2 options:

- submersible water pump: placed in the water tank, started by the MV output through the contactor. Most of these also have a float switch to protect the pump from dry-run (which should not happen because of the tank filling circuit).

  - Pro: Fairly cheap solution
  - Con: if I also want to use the water during the house renovation conveniently, I might need to add additional switches (remote switches) to the contactor input. Also I'm not sure, what happens if 1 of the zone valves does not open, and the pump output is blocked. If I have to install a pressure switch, the price would be in the range of the second option.
- domestic waterwork (commonly called as pump or water pump, as FreeMan pointed out in the comments): I won't be able to place it above the tank, but next to it and below water level, so extra valves might be needed (I don't entirely know what, where and why?)

  - Pro: I don't need contactor, if I need the water elsewhere, I can simply start it by opening the tube, it has a built-in pressure regulation and all the protection necessary.
  - Con: 2-3x more expensive than the first option, maintenance is necessary (membrane) + I don't know what auxiliary stuff is necessary (input tube, input filter and check valve, maintenance valve on the input?).

I know about the electric side of the problem, but I don't have experience with these kind of pumps.

Did I forget any of the possible issues?

Is a blocked tube really a problem for the submersible pump, and if yes, why and how to overcome it cheaply?

Note: I need the automation, because I won't be there all summer, I can only visit every 2-3 weeks.

Comment: What is "domestic waterwork"? We can't tell you which is the right solution for you - you're asking for opinions there which is explicitly [off-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @FreeMan: i translated it from german, which seemed to provide the appropriate results in google, so i sticked to the term. I meant something like this: https://www.einhell.at/en/garden/water-pumps/water-works/ if there is a better term for it, pls. help me out with it, I'll correct the question

Comment: Fair enough. Your English is quite good! I'd suggest that those are just "pumps" (or "water pumps") as opposed to "submersible pumps". There's probably a _more_ technical name for them for someone who works in the industry, but that would probably be sufficient for most folks.

Comment: regarding off-topic: 2 of the 3 questions are clearly non opinion based, and I provided the use cases for the last one - so i think it can be answered objectively, I can remove it if it's your only objection

Comment: That would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The usual set up does not have any tank to hold water.

The irrigation controller turns on the well pump when it turns on a zone.
The water then flows from the pump through a filter, to the sprinklers.

Larger systems can have a pressure tank and switch at the well.

I don't see the need to pump the water to a tank and then pump it out again.

If the pressure is an issue there are regulators.

Comment: Thanks for the answer: the well is relatively deep, the well pump has to manage c.a. 15-16m. Not sure whether it would be a good idea to have the same pump handle the irrigation too. Besides i could also collect the rainwater from the roof into the tank.

Comment: @G.B.,  I'm in Fla.  almost every home has irrigation.  If the water used is supposed to also be potable a backflow prevention method  is used.  I have never encountered a holding tank.  Don't know what c.a. 15- 16m. is  an explanation would have been helpful.  Your solutions just seem far more complicated than necessary.

Comment: I understand, thanks for the feedback. Do you see any issue if one of the valves does not open? Can the pump break or damage the tubing, or do you see any other possible issues?

Comment: What pipes?  What are the pipes made of and the diameter?   What valves are you using?  You give no details here.  Any other possible issues?  Yes the whole concept is more complicated than it needs to be.   If the proper materials are used in the proper configuration irrigation systems and wells can work with normal maintenance for decades.  You have something other than that.